# How to create SQL with SUM and COUNT in the same query from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 1 table and I can run 2 separate sql queries that work well. I am trying to combine the 2 queries in to one.  The queries are both using data from the same table.  How to I simply combine a query the counts the number of categories and the other queries that SUMs the totals of the querys.

See image below - on what I have when I get the 2 queries
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Foj.jpg

I have tried to use this but it does not give me what I need

`SELECT category,SUM(estbudget) as estbudget,COUNT(*) as category,'count' FROM schedule GROUP BY category,estbudget ORDER by SUM(estbudget)`

Here are the 2 working queries

This gives me the count of categories
`SELECT category, COUNT(*) from schedule group by category ORDER by COUNT(*) DESC";`

This gives me the total cost per category
`SELECT category,SUM(estbudget) FROM schedule GROUP BY category ORDER by SUM(estbudget) DESC";`

This is the outcome I would like to use with 1 query
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK7HT.jpg

Comment: This has work SELECT category,SUM(estbudget) as estbudget,COUNT(*) as category,'count' 
FROM schedule GROUP BY category
ORDER by SUM(estbudget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks its worked SELECT category,SUM(estbudget) as estbudget,COUNT(*) as category,'count' FROM schedule GROUP BY category ORDER by SUM(estbudget)
I almost had it thanks @Fahmi

Comment: its not a right way to take one's answer and give the same answer by yourself and mark it as accepted !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - remove `estbudget` from `group by`

```
SELECT category,SUM(estbudget) as estbudget,COUNT(*) as 'count' 
FROM schedule GROUP BY category
ORDER by SUM(estbudget)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `COUNT(*) as \`count\`` ?